# Use a specific Scrapy downloader middleware per request

Tags: python, scrapy, crawlera

I use Crawlera as a IP rotating service to crawl a specific website which is banning my IP quickly but I have this problem only with one website out of a dozen.

As it is possible to register multiple middlewares for a Scrapy project, I wanted to know if it was possible to define the downloader middleware to use PER REQUEST.

So I could use my Crawlera's quota only for the problematic website and not for all my requests.

Comment: the answer is yes you can do this .. for more clear answer you needs to describe your problem more clearly .. are you crawling multiple domains in one spider ? or crawlera is enabled at project level and for every domain you have different spider ?

Comment: If you are using `scrapy-crawlera`, you can use `dont_proxy` on requests that do not need Crawlera: https://scrapy-crawlera.readthedocs.io/en/v1.6.0/#how-to-use-it

Comment: Thanks @Gallaecio this is the best way!

Answer (score 3):

One of possible solution - usage [`custom_settings`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#settings-per-spider) spider attribute (and removing `CrawleraMiddleware` from project settings 
(assuming that you have 1 spider per 1 website and `CrawleraMiddleware` enabled in project settings):

```
class ProblemSpider(scrapy.spider):

    custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES' : {'scrapy_crawlera.CrawleraMiddleware': 610},
        'CRAWLERA_ENABLED' : True,
        'CRAWLERA_APIKEY' : '<API key>'}

    def parse(self, response):
....
```

In this case `CrawleraMiddleware` will be used only in spiders where it defined in their `custom_settings` attribute.